# Why does iPhone app update break my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I just released an iPhone app update and certain features don't work when the app is **updated**. More specifically, a plist that I download and store in Documents isn't displayed.

This worked fine in the previous app version and works fine if the new version is downloaded directly from the App Store. If someone upgrades, then uninstalls and reinstalls the app, that works too.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Apparently the app upgrade process completely replaces the app bundle but keeps external files and settings (NSUserdefaults, etc.).

More importantly, does anyone know how to fix this? My last resort is contacting my substantial user base and telling them to uninstall and reinstall, which is bad for my reputation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Um, don't stick the plist in Documents?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to write some code that checks the plist in the document folder against the plist in your bundle and then move the new plist to the documents folder, or at least updates the old key-values to your new key-values.

This is the way that preset Core Data stores are initialised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there already is a check in place (although I'm checking against a server, not the bundle). And when I "update" the app from Xcode, it keeps all the files, user defaults and everything works. So this is really a problem with the App Store update process.